# Elasticsearch - use terms bucket key as filter variable

Tags: elasticsearch

I index these:

```
POST nephi/boat/1
{
    "plates": {
        "id": 123,
        "type": "brass"
    },
    "compass": {
        "id": 123,
        "name": "liahona"
    }
}

POST nephi/boat/2
{
    "plates": {
        "id": 100,
        "type": "brass"
    },
    "compass": {
        "id": 234,
        "name": "liahona"
    }
}
```

I use this search query so I can do an aggregation where `plates.id` and `compass.id` are equal:

```
POST nephi/boat/_search
{
   "aggs": {
      "terms_agg": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "plates.id"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "filter_agg": {
               "filter": {
                  "term": {
                     "compass.id": 123
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "size": 0
}
```

Rather than using `"compass:id": 123`, I'd like to be able to use a variable in place of 123, like `"compass:id": "__bucket_key"`, where `__bucket_key` would reference 123 on the first doc above, and 100 on the second doc above (the `plates.id`s).

Is something like this possible?

Comment: You want to aggregate on plates.id where `plates.id == compass.id` ??

Comment: @Richa, yes. It might seem silly to do in this example, but I want to do that so I can do another metric sub-aggregation (like count or sum), only on docs where ```plates.id == compass.id```.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, you don't have to aggregate on `plates.id` . Try using [Script Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/query-dsl-script-query.html) :

```
   "filter": {
    "script": {
       "script": "doc['plates.id'].value == doc['compass.id'].value"
    }
}
```

This will fetch you all those documents which have same plates and compass id.
Then you can apply `metric aggregation` or so.

Make sure you enable scripting.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to accomplish what I need without scripting, but I may have to do something like that.  Thanks.